# Create an array of size N and then assign to each element the value "[ ]"

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to create an array in C and then assign to every value in that array the string "[ ]".

---

**This is what I have in mind:**

```
char Array[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    Array[i]="[ ]";
}
```

---

**What is the correct approach to doing that?**

Comment: `Array[i] = 'a';` or `Array[i] = 0;` and so on. You can't assign `"[ ]"` to any element, that would require a different array type.

Comment: What type is that?

Comment: In the context, it would need to be `char *Array[N];` note that you can't copy a string with `=` so here there is an array of pointers.

Comment: And how do I assign "[   ]" to its elements?

Comment: You can't. You can assign a pointer to it with `Array[i] = "[ ]";` or you can have a 2-D array. I suggest you read the chapter in your book about arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow is a sample working code you customize to your taste:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  // for strcpy: use to copy one string into another

// set a symbolic constant 
#define N  10  

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // declare the array
   char Array[N][4];  // 4, because "[ ]" is 3+1 long

   for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
       strcpy(Array[i], "[ ]");
   }

   // print out the content for test purpose
   for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
       printf("Array[%d] = %s\n", i, Array[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted solution but I'd like to provide a bit more context that will help people who are used to higher-level languages like Java and C++ understand why these steps are needed when writing this algorithm in C vs. in a newer language.

For starters, not every C compiler will allow you to create an array with a size determined by a variable (this is called a Variable Length Array, or VLA--you can read more about them here: [How do I declare a variable sized array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18936855/10504837)). Unfortunately you can't even declare a const variable for the number of terms you want in your array (read more about that here: [Can a const variable be used to declare the size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18848537/10504837)). So that's why you're stuck typing the literals everywhere in the program or using preprocessor commands like I've demonstrated.

Next, the length of a char array in C is the number of chars it can hold. However, since each of your terms is 3 characters long plus the null character at the end you need the array to be 4 times longer than the number of terms. You can use two See the code below for how to declare this.

Finally, you need to #include the string.h header file in order to be able to work with strings in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  #define N_TERMS 6
  #define L_TERM 4
  char term[L_TERM] = "[ ]";
  char Array[N_TERMS * L_TERM] = ""; //array should be the size of the product of number of terms and length of term

  for(int i = 0; i < N_TERMS; i++){
    strcat(Array, term); //strcat adds the second string to the end of the first
  }
  printf("%s", Array); //prints the entire string
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you `strcat()` 6 terms together, you'll get one terminating null, not 6, so 6 * 3 + 1 would be sufficient space.

Answer (score -1):

A char is one character. Which would be in single quotes not double quotes. "[ ]" is three character. [, the space and ] are together three characters. Each index in a char array can only hold one character at a time, so the [ or the space or the ] or some other character.

Comment: Note that "[ ]" is a string literal that is associated with an array of 4 `char`s, not 3; you seem to have forgotten the `\0` terminator.